# Account: Mockito Test Account

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am writing unit test using Mockito for a method which returns Account object.

I am creating a new account as following:

```
Private Account testAccount = new Account("name", "type");
```

Code is not crashing but I am always getting this exception when I debug:

> Method threw 'java.lang.RuntimeException' exception. Cannot evaluate android.accounts.Account.toString()

And `testAccount.name` and `testAccount.type` is always `null`.

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong or if there is a proper way to mock it and get same account name and type as defined at time of initialisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague at work figured this out that we have to do reflection for the Account object as its fields are defined **final**, so you have to do it as following:

```
Account account = new Account("MyAccount", "SomeType");
Field nameField = account.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
nameField.setAccessible(true);
nameField.set(account, "your value");

// Set whatever field you want to configure
Field typeField = account.getClass().getDeclaredField("type");
typeField.setAccessible(true);
typeField.set(account, "your value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are running unittests. The Account class is only available as a Stub at unittest runtime. If you need the Account class you must run your tests on an Android Emulator (Instrumented Tests). Other option would be to mock all methods you need from the Stub.